# CSS Star Radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I found a code from http://jsfiddle.net/CAVpz/, I just need to understand the logic behind the hover styling how does it highlight the other radio buttons when i hover over the custom radio button, this code isn't an ordinary CSS code. 
Please it would be real helpful, if someone can give a brief idea on how this code works.

```
 <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1"><i></i>
 <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2"><i></i>
 <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3"><i></i>
 <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4"><i></i>
 <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5"><i></i>
</span>
<br><br>
<span class="star-rating star-3">     
 <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1"><i></i>
 <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2"><i></i>
 <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3"><i></i>
</span>


.star-rating {
 font-size: 0;
 white-space: nowrap;
 display: inline-block;
 /* width: 250px; remove this */
 height: 50px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAgMjAiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDIwIDIwIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48cG9seWdvbiBmaWxsPSIjREREREREIiBwb2ludHM9IjEwLDAgMTMuMDksNi41ODMgMjAsNy42MzkgMTUsMTIuNzY0IDE2LjE4LDIwIDEwLDE2LjU4MyAzLjgyLDIwIDUsMTIuNzY0IDAsNy42MzkgNi45MSw2LjU4MyAiLz48L3N2Zz4=');
 background-size: contain;
}
.star-rating i {
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
 /* width: 20%; remove this */
 z-index: 1;
 background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAgMjAiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDIwIDIwIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48cG9seWdvbiBmaWxsPSIjRkZERjg4IiBwb2ludHM9IjEwLDAgMTMuMDksNi41ODMgMjAsNy42MzkgMTUsMTIuNzY0IDE2LjE4LDIwIDEwLDE2LjU4MyAzLjgyLDIwIDUsMTIuNzY0IDAsNy42MzkgNi45MSw2LjU4MyAiLz48L3N2Zz4=');
 background-size: contain;
}
.star-rating input {
 -moz-appearance: none;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 opacity: 0;
 display: inline-block;
 /* width: 20%; remove this */
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 z-index: 2;
 position: relative;
}
.star-rating input:hover + i,
.star-rating input:checked + i {
 opacity: 1;
}
.star-rating i ~ i {
 width: 40%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i {
 width: 60%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i ~ i {
 width: 80%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i {
 width: 100%;
}
::after,
::before {
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.star-rating.star-5 {width: 250px;}
.star-rating.star-5 input,
.star-rating.star-5 i {width: 20%;}
.star-rating.star-5 i ~ i {width: 40%;}
.star-rating.star-5 i ~ i ~ i {width: 60%;}
.star-rating.star-5 i ~ i ~ i ~ i {width: 80%;}
.star-rating.star-5 i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~i {width: 100%;}

.star-rating.star-3 {width: 150px;}
.star-rating.star-3 input,
.star-rating.star-3 i {width: 33.33%;}
.star-rating.star-3 i ~ i {width: 66.66%;}
.star-rating.star-3 i ~ i ~ i {width: 100%;}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question is likely to be closed as "off topic" as these are not the kinds of questions we handle here. There are many tutorial sites on the web to learn how HTML, CSS, and JavaScript work and you are better off doing your research first. Then, if you have a ***specific*** question, post it here.

Comment: "this code isn't an ordinary CSS code" Looks like it to me

Comment: Maybe this will help you understand: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok lets break it down for you. Here we are applying [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) with th "+" sign. The adjacent sibling selector selects all elements that are the adjacent siblings of a specified element. For example:

```css
    div + P {
      color: blue;
      border: 1px solid;
    }
    
    div{
      border: 1px solid;
    
    }
```

```html
<div><p> child</p></div>
<p>I am your Adjacent sibling</p>
```

The above code will select the p outside of div as it is adjacent element. So here on hovering input field, since its ajacent is `i` we add ajacent combinator.

```
.star-rating input:hover + i,
```

Next we are selecting and showing the stars selected wtih this css:

```
.star-rating input:checked + i{
   opacity: 1;
}
```

On clicking, the input field gets checked which then simply makes the i tag(star) visible with opacity 1. Next, we are applying [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator), which simply just selects siblings of a specifc element.

```css
div ~ p {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>Paragraph 1.</p>

<div>
  <p>Paragraph 2.</p>
</div>

<p>I am sibling</p>
<code>Some code.</code>
<p>I am sibling</p>
<p>I am sibling</p>
<p>I am sibling</p>
```

So here, on hovering the last star which is 5. we want all stars to be shown selected as well and general sibling does that for us.

```
.star-rating i ~ i {
  width: 40%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i {
  width: 60%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i ~ i {
  width: 80%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Finall we assign differnt background to starts in percentage:

```
.star-rating.star-5 {width: 250px;}
.star-rating.star-5 input,
.star-rating.star-5 i {width: 20%;}
.star-rating.star-5 i ~ i {width: 40%;}
.star-rating.star-5 i ~ i ~ i {width: 60%;}
.star-rating.star-5 i ~ i ~ i ~ i {width: 80%;}
.star-rating.star-5 i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~i {width: 100%;}

.star-rating.star-3 {width: 150px;}
.star-rating.star-3 input,
.star-rating.star-3 i {width: 33.33%;}
.star-rating.star-3 i ~ i {width: 66.66%;}
.star-rating.star-3 i ~ i ~ i {width: 100%;}
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

In few words:

1. We have 2 backgrounds, 1 with empty stars, and 1 with filled;
2. We assign empty background to span-wrapper;
3. We assign filled background to each `i` element, and differ width of each `i` in % that it will cover (20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100%);
4. On hover we change opacity for `i:background` that was hovered.